# Unable to run SonarQube and Jenkins on single instance of AWS

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, sonarqube

I have installed Jenkins and SonarQube on one of the EC2 instances on AWS. Under the security group, I have configured http, https, ssh and **All TCP**.

For "All TCP" port range is 0-65535.

I started SonarQube on http://ip:9000 and was able to interact with it. Next, I started Jenkins on http://ip:8080 and again I was able to interact with it, but once I switch back to the earlier URL i.e. SonarQube (http://ip:9000) it got failed to start and it happened vice-versa as well.

- For Security group, the source is **My IP** *e.g. 11.22.333.44/55*
- Used "systemctl start jenkins" command to start Jenkins
- Used "./sonar.sh start" command to start SonarQube
- Amazon Machine Image (AMI) --> Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.5 (HVM)

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to know the port in question (9000), stand up:

```
netstat -ntl
```

Depending on the result, you will have to add the firewall rules for ipv4, within the Operating System:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone = public --permanent --list-ports
sudo firewall-cmd --zone = public --permanent --add-port = 9000 / tcp
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

Comment: I am getting "sudo: firewall-cmd: command not found" in my terminal :(

Comment: @Nitish kumar You can try this:  'sudo iptables --line -vnL' and 'sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 9000 -j ACCEPT' and save 'sudo service iptables save'